# Assigning values to specific entries of a matrix within foreach in R

Tags: r, geospatial, parallel.foreach

So I am trying to construct a distance matrix between some stores and some locations. Since the number of stores (n) and locations (m) are enormous hence the resulting distance matrix is large (n*m), I want to compute the distance only for locations that are close to a given store, so ideally it would be a sparse matrix with a lot of *NA*s. I try to do using parallel computing in R with *foreach* and the code is as follow

```
foreach(store_id = 1:n) %dopar% {
  
  # obtain the ith store's lat/long coordinaters
  store_lat = latlist[store_id]
  store_long = longlist[store_id]
  
  # return candidate locations that are close enough to the given store
  candidate_list = location[location["LATITUDE"] > store_lat - 0.25 & ... & location["LONGITUDE"] < store_lon + 0.25, ]["ID"])]

  foreach (location_id = candidate_list, .combine=c) %dopar% {
    tract_lat = location[location["ID"] == location_id,]$LATITUDE
    tract_lon = location[location["ID"] == location_id,]$LONGITUDE
    # compute the distance and store it in distance matrix
    dist = distm(c(store_lon, store_lat), c(tract_lon, tract_lat), fun = distHaversine)
    dist_matrix[store_id, location_id] = dist
  }
}
```

However, it turns out that the distance were computed but not stored in the distance matrix, i.e. *dist_matrix*. I looked up other posts and it seems that *foreach* is something more like *lapply* rather than *for* loop. But since I am only computing the distance for a subset of columns (locations that are close), and the subset will depend on which row (store) it is in, I'm not sure how exactly am I going to tackle this in R.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Spares matrices are often stored in [i, j, k] (row, column, value) form.  There is a `Matrix` package among others that handles sparse matrices: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/working-with-sparse-matrices-in-r-programming/  Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! My question is here is more about how to do computation using the parallel computing tool in R, rather than how to handle sparse matrices. The problem in the current code is that it is not storing any value to the matrix at all